# setting nested element width to column width

Tags: susy-compass, susy, susy-sass

I'm having some troubles to find the right way to approach this problem:

I've got a situation like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li class="section">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="path/to/img.png">
            <span class="title">Section 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="section">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="path/to/img-2.png">
            <span class="title">Section 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now within a 12 cols grid, I've got that `.section` is defined as:

```
.section {
    position: relative;
    @include span(6);
}
```

and so far so good.
Now I've defined the `.title` to be hover the image like:

```
.title {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[edit] the configuration I'm using has got the following definition:

```
susy: (
    gutter-position: inside;
);
```

but I can't use `width: 100%;` because it won't work, and I do need to manually give it a `width`, whereas a value computed out of `span()` won't work e.g. `width: span(6 of 6);` due to the `gutter-position` that sets the padding instead of the margin.

Is there any good or consistent way to go around this problem?

Should I just stick to the default `after` or `before` for `gutter-position`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `left` property in order to align your title with the container, and then you can either set `right` or `width` to get the full width:

```
.title {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

or

```
.title {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```